# is it possible to run two for loops simultaneously?

Tags: java

I was trying to get a differnce of the diagonal elements of a 2d square matrix

```
static int diagonalDifference(int[][] arr) {
    int left=0,right=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(i==j){
                left=left+arr[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i=0,int j=n;i<n;i++,j--){
        right=right+arr[i][j];
    }


}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please have a look at the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) on [How do i ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Currently, it is not clear what exactly you are asking. Besides that, you code does not compile, so it would really help to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes, you can run different code (e.g. loops) at the same time - you could achieve that running them in detached threads.. but idk what do you want achieve doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you start worrying about running loops in parallel, worry about writing simple, *correct* code.

For instance:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
        if(i==j){
            left=left+arr[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

These nested loops will run `n*n` times. But you only do anything if `i==j`; so you waste effort by looping. Simpler just to remove the inner loop, and use:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
  left += arr[i][i];
}
```

Which only does `n` iterations: not only is the code simpler, it is also faster.

That was inefficient; your other loop is actually wrong:

```
for(int i=0,int j=n;i<n;i++,j--){
    right=right+arr[i][j];
}
```

Syntax error aside, this would fail with an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` on the first iteration, presumably, since `arr[i].length == n`, but `j == n`. So initialize `j=n-1`.

You don't need separate loops here anyway:

```
for(int i=0, j=n-1;i<n;i++, j--){
  left += arr[i][i];
  right += arr[i][j];
}
```

With just one loop, there is no need to try to make loops run simultaneously.